# First note of a beamed group must never fall on an off beat, unless it is preceded by a rest of a dotted note

Tags: beaming

Here's an image related to my question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU0ZO.png

Below this image it says:

> Bar 3 is incorrect, because the 3rd quaver in the group should have a stronger accent than the first quaver. The importance of the third beat of the bar is hidden.

So why is this a rule? Can't the musician hit an accented beat on the third quaver?

Comment: I've never heard about this rule. May be it is a  rule for teachers dictating  rhythm patterns?

Comment: I've edited the post, it might be clearer to figure out now.

Comment: Bar 3 is not incorrect, it;s just bad practice. There is no rule, just recommendations based on experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the USA we tend to format phone numbers like this:
1(555) 412-1234 or 1-555-412-1234. 
Pretty easy to read right?

What about this:
15554121234

Same info but much harder to read.

This is the same. There is a unwritten rule that we use what I was taught to call “the imaginary bar line”. It is strictly for making the music easier to read by breaking things in to smaller more manageable chunks in a predictable way.

The same way you wouldn’t bar two eighth notes spanning over two measures (from beat 4 to beat 1) we also don’t bar notes between the 2nd and 3rd beat because there is an imaginary bar line that divides the bar in half.

I think there are other imaginary bar lines that take place in the measure when you are dealing with faster notes like 16ths and 32nds.

Check out here for more info:

https://online.berklee.edu/takenote/imaginary-barlines/

Comment: See also the [IU Jacobs School's Music Notation Style Guide](https://music.indiana.edu/departments/academic/composition/style-guide/#rhythm) for another equivalent way of thinking about these "imaginary barlines".

Comment: @michael_seifret that is an excellent source.

Comment: It really is.  I never miss an opportunity to link to it.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's 'incorrect' because in even time signatures, (4/4, 6/8 etc.) it's easier to read bars when they can be seen to split, physically, into two equal halves. Sadly, it's not always the case these days, but it definitely makes life easier.

Response to comments - keeping bars in two halves makes it necessary to use ties when something is syncopated. Some readers (inc. me) find that easier to see that there is indeed a syncopation.

Piiperi - from where I stand, the point of any written music is to make it as simple as possible for as many players as possible to be able to read it easily. If that necessitates keeping bars splittable into halves, then so be it. Of course, seasoned readers have no problems even 'reading fly excrement' (it's a muso phrase!), but why exclude the others, who need simplicity? Not sure that U.K.'dumb' is equivalent to yours...

Comment: Right, but how 'exactly' is it easier? Is it because the way the notes are written are compatible with our counting pattern and so it feels more 'natural'?

Comment: It's a very characteristically Western thing. :) Of course, the whole notation system is Western, but in it, rhythms are assumed to be dumb by default, and deviations from dumbness are expanded and written. ;) So, if there's a syncopated phrase crossing the half-bar boundary, you have to break it down to half-bar pieces, because otherwise poor players don't understand it. Western musician. Simple rhythm. Short sentence. Please. No fancy thing. Musician not understand! Assume dumb musician. Keep simple. Not hard! ;)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica It has nothing to do with poor players not understanding it. Professionals also prefer the bar split in the middle because it makes sight-reading so much easier.

Comment: @PiedPiper ”easier ...” for certain music and people in a certain culture at least. I once attended a Ghanaian rhythm seminar/lesson and the drum rhythms were taught as a chain of separate phrases of various lengths that didn’t seem to make sense until they were all put together, creating a pattern that I heard as four bars of 4/4 or something. But it was not split to sections of half ”bars”, which would have made it much easier for me to understand. The teacher explained that the whole counting beats thing was foreign to him when he first got in contact with Western musicians. :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica This whole question is about the notation of **western** music. I'm sure Ghanaian drum music has different notation conventions (if indeed it's notated at all).

Comment: @PiedPiper Of course it's about Western music, that's what I was trying to say. If you don't find these cultural differences interesting, your bad. :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I **do** find these differences interesting, but this question is probably not the best place to discuss them.

Comment: @PiedPiper - if Ghanian drum music ***is*** notated, there is a little relevance. If it's ***not***, then it's quite irrelevant - here.

Answer (score 0):

This rule I know in other words:

The middle of a measure (4/4 time) should be clear separated  to be easier read and recognized. So it doesn't make sense to beam the notes passing the middle part of the bar. This is why bar 3 is incorrect.

As you can see the rule is concerning the notation, not the rhythm pattern.
The rhythm of bar 2 and 3 are identical.

Comment: I could tolerate  a longer passage of the 332 or 12221 pattern breaking this rule ...

Answer (score 0):

I take exception to the part of the explanation which says the 3rd beat is emphasized. That's simply not true (except for rock music  :-)  ).  In fact the beaming as written suggests the four eighth notes constitute a 'run' up to the 4th beat, and if anything the 4th beat would get some emphasis.

If you want the 3rd beat to be the strong one, then I would agree that the eighths should be in two groups, and probably put an emphasis mark of one kind or another over the first eighth note of the 3rd beat.

Comment: This comes over as more comment than answer.

Comment: @Tim  probably true -- I should emphasize the part about using beaming to "lead" the performer to the desired heavy - beat pattern.